# Use of window() function in TensorFlow Dataset to access more than one row

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I've got a problem with transforming the dataset read from .csv files by [tf.data.experimental.CsvDataset](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/experimental/CsvDataset) into "timeseries".

What I'm trying to do is to access more than one row of the dataset at once in order to append features of previous 2 rows to the current row and keep the label of the current row. I'd like to do it for every row (apart from the first two). I thought that applying `window()` function is the right approach but now I'm not so sure.

The original dataset consisting of approximately 300 columns is created by reading a set of .csv files like this:

```
ds = tf.data.experimental.CsvDataset(
            filenames,
            [tf.float32] * len(columns_indices_to_parse),
            header=True,
            select_cols=columns_indices_to_parse
        )
```

For reproducibility I'm using the combination of Dataset.from_tensor_slices() and Dataset.zip():

```
import tensorflow as tf

tf.enable_eager_execution()

with tf.Graph().as_default(), tf.Session() as sess:
    # Simulate what's being returned from CsvDataset():
    feature_1_ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices([1., 3., 5., 7., 9.])
    feature_2_ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices([2., 4., 6., 8., 10.])
    label_1_ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices([1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0])

    ds = tf.data.Dataset.zip((feature_1_ds, feature_2_ds, label_1_ds))

    # Do transformations to obtain "timeseries" data.
    def _parse_function_features(*row):
        features = tf.stack(row[:2], axis=-1)
        return features

    def _parse_function_labels(*row):
        labels = tf.stack(row[2:], axis=-1)
        return labels

    def _reshape(x):
        # Flatten rows into one.
        return tf.reshape(x, shape=[-1])

    ds_features = ds.map(_parse_function_features).window(3).flat_map(lambda x: x.batch(3)).map(_reshape)
    ds_labels = ds.map(_parse_function_labels).skip(2)
    ds = tf.data.Dataset.zip((ds_features, ds_labels))

    iter = ds.make_one_shot_iterator().get_next()
    # Show dataset contents
    print('Result:')
    while True:
        try:
            print(sess.run(iter))
        except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError:
            break
```

I'm still getting my head around window() transformation, I saw [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/27119) GitHub issue but it doesn't solve my problem.

What I'm getting now is:

```
(array([1., 2., 3., 4., 5., 6.], dtype=float32), array([0.], dtype=float32))
(array([ 7.,  8.,  9., 10.], dtype=float32), array([1.], dtype=float32))
```

The problem is that it behaves like batch - processes rows in triples. What I'd like to achieve is the following:

```
(array([1., 2., 3., 4., 5., 6.], dtype=float32), array([0.], dtype=float32)) # with label of the third row
(array([3., 4., 5., 6., 7., 8.], dtype=float32), array([1.], dtype=float32)) # with label of the fourth row
(array([5., 6., 7., 8., 9., 10.], dtype=float32), array([0.], dtype=float32)) # with label of the fifth row
```

I'm stuck a bit, I'm not sure if using window() function for accessing more than one row of the dataset is even the right approach. I've asked very similar question previously but I deleted it as I think I've included too much details, here I've tried to keep it as lean as possible. Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok after tackling the problem from many sides I've finally managed to achieve the required result. I've got two solutions: one that processes features and labels as separate datasets and the one which appies transformations to the dataset in one go. Both might be useful depending on the use case.

1. Process features and labels as separate datasets:

```
import tensorflow as tf

tf.enable_eager_execution()

with tf.Graph().as_default(), tf.Session() as sess:
    # Simulate what's being returned from CsvDataset():
    feature_1_ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices([1., 3., 5., 7., 9.])
    feature_2_ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices([2., 4., 6., 8., 10.])
    label_1_ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices([1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0])

    ds = tf.data.Dataset.zip((feature_1_ds, feature_2_ds, label_1_ds))

    # Do transformations to obtain "timeseries" data.
    def _parse_function_features(*row):
        features = tf.stack(row[:2], axis=-1)
        return features

    def _parse_function_labels(*row):
        labels = tf.stack(row[2:], axis=-1)
        return labels

    def _reshape(x):
        # Flatten rows into one.
        return tf.reshape(x, shape=[-1])

    ds_features = ds.map(_parse_function_features).window(3, shift=1).flat_map(lambda x: x.batch(3)).map(_reshape)
    ds_labels = ds.map(_parse_function_labels).window(3, shift=1).flat_map(lambda x: x.skip(2))
    ds = tf.data.Dataset.zip((ds_features, ds_labels))

    iter = ds.make_one_shot_iterator().get_next()
    # Show dataset contents
    print('Result:')
    while True:
        try:
            print(sess.run(iter))
        except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError:
            break
```

2. Transform the dataset in one go:

```
import tensorflow as tf

tf.enable_eager_execution()

with tf.Graph().as_default(), tf.Session() as sess:
    # Simulate what's being returned from CsvDataset():
    feature_1_ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices([1., 3., 5., 7., 9.])
    feature_2_ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices([2., 4., 6., 8., 10.])
    label_1_ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices([1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0])

    ds = tf.data.Dataset.zip((feature_1_ds, feature_2_ds, label_1_ds))

    # Do transformations to obtain "timeseries" data.
    def _parse_function(*row):
        features = tf.stack(row[:2], axis=-1)
        labels = tf.stack(row[2:], axis=-1)
        return features, labels


    def _reshape(features, labels):
        # Flatten features into one row.
        return tf.reshape(features, shape=[-1]), labels


    ds = ds.map(_parse_function)
    ds = ds.window(3, shift=1)
    ds = ds.flat_map(lambda x, y: tf.data.Dataset.zip((x.batch(3), y.skip(2))))
    ds = ds.map(_reshape)

    iter = ds.make_one_shot_iterator().get_next()
    # Show dataset contents
    print('Result:')
    while True:
        try:
            print(sess.run(iter))
        except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError:
            break
```

For both of these the output is:

```
Result:
(array([1., 2., 3., 4., 5., 6.], dtype=float32), array([0.], dtype=float32))
(array([3., 4., 5., 6., 7., 8.], dtype=float32), array([1.], dtype=float32))
(array([ 5.,  6.,  7.,  8.,  9., 10.], dtype=float32), array([0.], dtype=float32))
```